# How to change the Ubuntu prompt

Tags: linux, shell, prompt

Hello I´m using Xubuntu and I want to change the prompt.

My actual prompt is to long, if I´m in a long path like:

Document/SubFolder_1/SubFolder_2/SubFolder_x/

it appear something like

```
my_name@CMGBiotools-VirtualBox :~ Document/SubFolder_1/subFolder_2/SubFolder_x/$
```

so I just want my_name and the last folder, something like:

```
my_name: SubFolder_x$
```

If I type  `echo $PS1` in the terminal, this is what appears:

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

and  the .bashrc looks like:

```
# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

which of those lines do I have to modified ??

Thanks So Much !!!

Answer (score 0):

put this in your *.bashrc*

```
PS1="[\u: \W]\$ "
export PS1
```

there is a whole bunch to read [Prompt Statement variables](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-prompt.html)

Comment: Thanks So Much, it Works :)) 